# Выборка рандомной строки каждого типа

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть схема таблицы следующего вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо построить выборку, чтобы каждый запрос выдавал рандомные строки группируя по number_task.
Я попробовал сделать что-то типа такого:

```html
SELECT number_task, task FROM informatica GROUP BY number_task, task  ORDER BY random() limit 2;
```

Но это не дало нужного эффекта.

Для примера.

Даны данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

О.Р.
Различные вариации типа:

Задание 1 | 1

Задание 2 | 2

Главное, чтобы number_task в результате выборки был уникален.

**UPDATE:**
Вывел EXPLAIN для запроса (схема таблицы обновлена):

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE ,BUFFERS ) SELECT * FROM (SELECT tasks.*, row_number over (partition by type order by random()) as seqnum from tasks WHERE subject_id = 2 AND status = true) as inf where seqnum = 1
```

1 миллион записей
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

10 миллионов записей
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но никак не получается оптимизировать его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой вариант решения:

```html
SELECT id, task, number_task FROM  (SELECT informatica.*, row_number() over 
(partition by number_task order by random()) as seqnum from informatica) 
as inf where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct number_task, 
      first_value(task) over(partition by number_task order by random()) 
FROM informatica limit 2;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: А если нужно еще поле id добавить, то для этого придется вложенный запрос делать?

Comment: Полагаю, что так.